# Swift REPL: how to save/load the REPL state? (a.k.a. suspend/resume, snapshot, clone)

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop

In the Swift REPL, what is a way to preserve the REPL state?

- For example, I want to do a bunch of work in the REPL, then save it, so I can load it later.
- This concept might be named save/load, suspend/resume, snapshot/clone,  serialize/deserialize, etc.

Any solution that gets me toward this will help, even if it's a hack like these:

- Record all the history lines, then replay them in another REPL.
- Serialize all the objects, then deserialize them in another REPL.
- Snapshot the RAM or VM, then clone it to another machine.
- Save a core image of the global state, then execute it later.

My goal is to save REPL work on one machine, then load it on another machine.

I only need the final state; I don't need stacks, or history, or handles, etc.

The XCode Playgrounds have a similar feature, using "Save", which externalizes content.

Comment: I doubt Swift has any support for this (and such generally *does* need support). If the REPL was run inside a VM with sleep support .. but alas such "images" make SmallTalk pretty much one-of-a-kind. I'm also not aware of any process-based snapshots tools, but I haven't looked.

Comment: why not use playground?

Comment: @huocp Because the Swift REPL is great - in my experience it's faster and lighter-weight than a playground.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this could help you a bit.

Just found out actually Swift REPL save current session in a file.

Type `__FILE__` in REPL, you will see the session file.

```
  1> __FILE__
$R0: String = "/var/folders/6j/xs_0g88d55dgprjrwdws898w0000gn/T/lldb/3869/repl1.swift"
```

You can view the file content, it keeps tracking current REPL session.
I am sure you can build an one line Swift code to copy that file into your save folder, which you have to run at end of your session.

BTW, in that temp folder, the `repl.swift` is actually more compact than `repl1.swift`. You probably want to copy `repl.swift`.

Comment: Thanks! The Swift REPL seems to be creating many files in the __FILE__ directory. Each REPL command seems to create two files: a .swift file and .cpp file. The .swift file without a number ("repl.swift") does seem to be tracking all the REPL lines that successfully execute. There doesn't seem to be a way to replay it into a new REPL -- I'll try to find that next.

Comment: What about processing the file to filter out all comments and then just piping what's left it into an invocation of swift ?

Comment: This doesn't work in Swift 3.1 anymore. `__FILE__` has been renamed to `#file` and it will just output `repl.swift`. You can however use `find /var/folders/ -name repl.swift` and look through the matches.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the classic command line utility `expect`.

`expect` replays a script of text-based interactions, watching for expected responses. Of course this requires that you author an expect script.

However, if you install expect from a package manager (like MacPorts), then it will also install the command `autoexpect`, which can watch your keystrokes and generate an `expect` script automatically.

For instance, you could do:

```
  autoexpect -f myscript swift
```

then interact on the repl, and quit when you're done. Then later you could do

```
  ./myscript
```

and it would replay that session.

The problem? `autoexpect` will generate a script that includes your final command of closing the REPL. I'm not sure if there's a way to run the script so that it omits that command, and passes control over to you.

This seems like exactly the sort of thing these utilities were originally designed for, so I would be surprised if the functionality is not already there.

Other similar commands are `script` and `interact`.

Comment: This is great general-purpose answer becaues the `expect` command and `script` command are so useful with many other goals - thank you for introducing me to these!