# save and restore nodejs REPL session

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I want to save the nodejs repl session to file. And from the file I can restore the status of that session, including user defined global variables and functions.

For example, if I type

```
a=1;b={x:1};b.__proto__={y:2};f=()=>{console.log(1)};
```

I want to save the session to a file and when restored the session from it, I can get a session with 3 global variables a,b,f, which have been properly set.

UPDATE 1

Different from node REPL's .save command and .load command, what I want is the current user defined global variables and functions properly Serialized and Deserialized.

Comment: For ref : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_repl_terminal.htm
.save command used to save file which has your session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suspend node REPL and resume at a later stage with all the environment preserved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031467/how-to-suspend-node-repl-and-resume-at-a-later-stage-with-all-the-environment-pr)

Comment: @YogeshPatel Can you please explain what will happen if I use .save and .load command? I can't find the details. Thank you.

Comment: @stdob-- I see. But I want the exact functionality to save and reload global variables only. Any suggestions?